# Во вложенном словаре нужно изменить значение для ключа и импортировать в json

Tags: python, словари

Есть json, в котором в разных местах есть ключ duration. Необходимо для всех ключей duration изменить значение на одинаковое.
Выполняю парсинг json.
Получаю многоуровневый вложенный словарь.
Нахожу все значения ключа duration во вложенных списках.
Изменяю значение для duration на новое.
Помещаю словарь в новый json файл.
Значение для ключа duration остается старым.
Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем моя ошибка?

```
import copy
import json
with open('test1.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
def find(collection, key):
    if isinstance(collection, dict):
        if key in collection:
            yield collection[key]
        for val in collection.values():
            yield from find(val, key)
    elif isinstance(collection, list):
        for val in collection:
            yield from find(val, key)

for val in find(data, 'duration'):
    print(val)
    val = 777
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for val in find(data, 'duration'):
    print(val)
    val = 777
```

Вы возвращаете просто значение. Менять значение само по себе - без толку, оно уже не привязано к коллекции. Вы меняете так только значение вашей локальной переменной `val`. Либо возвращайте саму коллекцию и меняйте там значение по ключу, либо лучше сразу в самой функции значение меняйте, примерно так:

```py
def change(collection, key, value):
    if isinstance(collection, dict):
        if key in collection:
            collection[key] = value # замена значения в коллекции
        for val in collection.values():
            change(val, key, value)
    elif isinstance(collection, list):
        for val in collection:
            change(val, key, value)

change(data, 'duration', 777)
```

Если всё же хотите сохранить итерирование и `yield`, то возвращайте коллекцию, содержащую ключ:

```py
def find(collection, key):
    if isinstance(collection, dict):
        if key in collection:
            yield collection # возврат коллекции в которой есть ключ
        for val in collection.values():
            yield from find(val, key)
    elif isinstance(collection, list):
        for val in collection:
            yield from find(val, key)

for collection in find(data, 'duration'):
    collection['duration'] = 777 # замена значения в коллекции
```

В этом случае вы возвратите **ссылку на коллекцию**, и значение будет изменено именно в самой коллекции.

Comment: Спасибо), все получилось.